# Learning Advanced PHP

Tags: php

I have been using PHP for quite some time now and was wondering what to study for looking into advanced topic - and what advanced topics those are. Please could you offer ideas on what type of projects or functions of PHP to use (which would give the greatest ability for me to take my PHP knowledge and skill to a higher level).

Comment: Could you provide some more details on your current experience?

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked (and/or closed) here before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**udpdate**

PHP has shifted these couple of years and now, more than ever, interoperability is of paramount importance. The single most important piece of PHP code would be the piece that can get along with all other bits.

[**PHP The Right Way**](http://www.phptherightway.com/) - a quick reference on how to do things
**[PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)** - or how to start writing PHP for the world

Advanced Computer Science topics are, for the most part, language agnostic ranging from algorithms to large scale software development.

---

**original answer:**

If you are not already into the two bellow I would seriously suggest you start there.

1. Objects
2. MVC (model view controller)

If you are asking this question you probably feel that there probably is a better way to reuse your code. That there probably is a better way to split logic from structure. If that is so go with the two bellow.

It will probably take a while to get used to `Objects` but it be worth while.

The one best thing I can suggest you is to embrace a framework.

- [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

You'll be forced to write your code following standards and you'll get a much better notion of how *advanced php software works*.

Comment: I have already looked at CodeIgniter for developing scripts and have decided it would be best to use it, or something similar - such as CakePHP - when designing my projects. The best option, in my opinion, would be for me to be able to learn how to write my own simplistic "framework" - as in using MVC without the need for an external infrastructure. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you these two great books:

[Sams: Advanced PHP Programming.](http://tona70.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/sams-advanced-php-programming/)

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/7218/samsadvancedphpjf1.jpg](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/7218/samsadvancedphpjf1.jpg)

[php|architect’s Guide to Enterprise PHP Development](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-enterprise-php-development/)

[alt text http://img3.immage.de/16028975acaphpgfx.jpg](http://img3.immage.de/16028975acaphpgfx.jpg)

.

**Note:** The [official PHP docs are always magical](http://php.net/docs.php) and you learn a lot from it really !

Comment: I think advanced is a very relative term.

Comment: I've ordered myself a copy of the second book - it looks very good and is well reviewed. Thanks for your suggestions.

EDIT: I have been doing PHP on-and-off for a couple of years but I find it hard to define my experience level. I have never attempted a project that I could not do - yet I have never attempted a vast or advanced project before.

Comment: @jSherz where exactly is the 2nd book well reviewed? I could only find one average 5-line review in Amazon..

Answer (score 7):

There are number of things which you can do to learn advance topics. 
Learn different types of php frameworks and architecture.
Explore advance open source projects such as content management systems. joomla mambo. 
Magento. How these are coded and their architecture are build.  Try to understand the architecture and techniques has been used in them.

Explore zend framework libraries, classes and different modules.

there are different php libraries which you can explore such as image magick, ffmpeg for video, PHP curl, PHP input out stream, 
Read specification of php 5.2 and 5.3. what is major difference in them. what is new in php 5.3.

There is whole lot of other stuff. keep exploring and keep learning. Over the internet, there are whole world open.

If you done all that then come up one step further, Join forums and different php programer communities such as Stack overflow, Keep helping others by solving different challenging problems. Sharing is caring. more you share more you gain.

Remember: The beginning of knowledge is the discovery of something we do not understand. (Frank. Herbert)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/

This "book" is pretty easy to read with tons of examples. It's split up into manageable sections and teaches you most of what you need to know to get started with a framework like CodeIgniter.

Comment: Unfortunately the link died.

Answer (score 2):

Explore www.php.net site, I guess it will give a lot of inspiration for your study.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at http://www.phpframeworks.com/ and pick one framework, and make a project, than try another one, try to understand why different framework use different techniques for some things and the same techniques for other things.

Perhaps you should try to create your own little framework, or to extend an existing frameworks with libraries you often need.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've been looking into using CakePHP and it seems a good starting ground for working with an advanced system for writing code. If I find it does not suit my style or I find issues then I can always try another one. Thanks again!